# apiの処理待ちの考え方

Tags: api

今まで使ったことあるAPIはリクエストを送ったら、レポートの結果が取得できるAPIを扱ってきました。

現在、使用を検討している
1.APIはリクエストを送ったら、そのリクエストのレポートIDが発行され、
2.発行されたIDを元にリクエストを出し、結果を取得できるAPIとなっています。

前者は処理にかかる時間も単に待っていたらいいのですが、
後者は最初の1.リクエストでレポートIDが発行されて、処理が完了される前に2を行うと、準備中のエラーが返ってきます。特に完了までの時間などもレスポンスがないため、完了時間がわかりません。
こういった場合は完了するまで定期的に2を行うのが一般的なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

はい、2を繰り返し行います。ポーリングといわれる手法になります

提供サービス（またはライブラリ等）によってはレポートの処理終了後にコールバックしてくれる場合もありますが、そういう仕組みがない場合はポーリングでリクエストし処理完了を待つことになります